# Gradle Build Failure: Couldn't find outer class

Tags: gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

When trying to build, I get this stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Couldn't find outer class com/xxx/CheckListPresenter$onAttached$1$5 of com/xxx/CheckListPresenter$onAttached$1$5$1
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:1079)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.ClassVsInterface.isOuterInterface(ClassVsInterface.java:56)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visitOuterClass(InterfaceDesugaring.java:246)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:638)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:477)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:361)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:314)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:711)
```

I checked the `CheckListPresenter` class and there doesn't appear to have any issues. I tried deleting the class just to see if it would build, but the error just moved on to another class stating the same issue.

The last time I touched this code was a good few months ago, so I am not sure what triggered the change.

Things that may matter: This is an Android project. This is written in Kotlin. This fails on the `transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug` gradle task

---

## Edits

*These are all just stabs in the dark I tried:*

- Creating a new project and moving in only my source code and gradle files.
- Dropping from java 8 to 7.
- Different version of JDK. I have tried 1.8.0_151 and 1.8.0_152.
- Adding `javaMaxHeapSize "4g"` to build.gradle.
- Upgrading everything: gradle wrapper and every dependency.
- Removed Dagger in favor of Koin
- Removed Kapt
- Used both Preview and Stable releases of Android Studio

Here is my [build scan](https://scans.gradle.com/s/7oejtgklrgbcy/console-log) for what good it will do

#### New discovery:

This is the snippet of code that is killing me:

```
view?.let { v ->
    v.getCancelClicks()
        .doOnSubscribe({ disposables.add(it) })
        .subscribe({
           v.showExitDialog()
              .filter { it }
              .subscribe({
                 cancel()
            }, this::onError)
           
         }, this::onError)
    }
```

What is strange, is neither one of these *alone* will give me issues

```
view?.let { v ->
    v.getCancelClicks()
        .doOnSubscribe({ disposables.add(it) })
        .subscribe({
            //removed 
         }, this::onError)
    }
}
```

or

```
view?.let { v ->
    v.showExitDialog()
        .filter { it }
        .subscribe({
           cancel()
        }, this::onError)
 }
```

But **together** they are a problem.

Something else of note, `view` is defined in the base class and is a generic.

Currently, my work around is to remove `view?.let{` and just use `view!!`. This is obviously a bug, but I am not sure who to report it to.  Gradle, Kotlin, JetBrains, God?

Comment: This problem may be related with ProGuard. Do you have it?

Comment: @comm1x No, I don't

Answer (score 12):

The problem resolved itself when I added `android.enableD8.desugaring = true` to `gradle.properties`

Comment: I tried that too. It didn't work for me, but I know it works for many.

Answer (score 1):

I have a way to work around this error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Couldn't find outer class com/iconfitness/iconaudit/common/fragments/SettingsFragment$onCreate$1$1 of com/iconfitness/iconaudit/common/fragments/SettingsFragment$onCreate$1$1$1`.

Just move this block code

```
v.showExitDialog()
              .filter { it }
              .subscribe({
                 cancel()
```

oo other method. I don't meet this problem anymore. I hope this will help you.

Comment: This isn't much different from what I did. I just don't get why, or who to report it to.

Comment: I meet this issue like you, and when i did like that, it worked. I don't know why too. Did you try that?

Comment: I didn't try your solution exactly; but if you see my solution above, you will see it is not much different.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is filed here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72750890.
Both solutions mentioned there worked for me:
adding `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'` to build.gradle or adding `android.enableD8.desugaring=true` to gradle.properties

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can substitute `let` by null checking. At least code started to compile after this

```
if (view!=null)
    view.showExitDialog()
        .filter { it }
        .subscribe({
           cancel()
        }, this::onError)
}
```